# leaderboard scores not showing UP

Tags: ios, xcode, leaderboard

I created a little app just to test out Game center i sign in i am able to increase the score but when i look at the leader board nothing is there

here is my code

```
- (IBAction)increaseScore:(id)sender {

currentScore+=4;
scoreLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",currentScore];
}

- (IBAction)showLeaderBoard:(id)sender {

GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderBoardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController    alloc]init];
leaderBoardController.category=@"1";
leaderBoardController.timeScope=GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
leaderBoardController.leaderboardDelegate=self;

[self presentModalViewController:leaderBoardController animated:YES];

}
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (IBAction)sumbitScore:(id)sender {

GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc]initWithCategory:@"1"];
//@"1" is the leaderboard ID
scoreReporter.value=currentScore;
[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"submit failed");
    }else{

        NSLog(@"access granted");

    }

}];

}
```

Comment: And i'm Getting @"access granted"not the error

Answer (score 1):

GameCenter will only show the leaderboard scores when there are two or more players on the leaderboard.

You will need a score submitted by another GameCenter account.  You could sign up for a second Apple Id to be able to send in scores from a 'second' player.